# update statements shows update count but not updating the table

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, update

I am facing a strange issue which I have never faced before. I have a update query like below

```
Update A
Set A.Col10 = E.Col10, A.Col11 = E.Col11
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN TableB B on A.Col1 = B.Col1
INNER JOIN TableC C on C.Col1 = B.Col2
INNER JOIN TableD D on D.Col1 = C.Col2
INNER JOIN TableE E on E.Col1 = D.Col2
WHERE D.Col3 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @ENDDate
AND E.Col10 <> A.Col10
```

When i am running above statement it is giving message that 810 rows are updated. but when I am selecting based on the same criteria I am still getting those 810 rows.

```
SELECT A.Col10 , E.Col10
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN TableB B on A.Col1 = B.Col1
INNER JOIN TableC C on C.Col1 = B.Col2
INNER JOIN TableD D on D.Col1 = C.Col2
INNER JOIN TableE E on E.Col1 = D.Col2
WHERE D.Col3 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @ENDDate
AND E.Col10 <> A.Col10
```

no matter how many times I update the table it is still showing the same count. now, my question is where I am going wrong and what are those records which got updated when actually no records are updated.

Comment: Are any triggers on it?

Comment: @sabinbio No, none of these tables have trigger.

Comment: If the result of those joins is not unique, sql server will update A.Col10 with every E.Col10 value that matches your query, so at the end there might be the same amount of rows in the second query as in the first statement.

Comment: For example - there are 81 A values and 11 E values, one A value match one E value, so sql server will update each A value 10 times = 810. The final result is the same(one A value match one E value), so when you select those values you still get 810 results.

Comment: @MichaelCherevko OMG! That makes complete sense. How can I miss that... I need to have another condition in where clause to get matching rows (1-1). I am sure that's the problem.. let me test with the new query and I will post my outcome here. I request  you to please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: In the second select are A.Col10 , E.Col10 in fact <>?  AND E.Col10 <> A.Col10 should return only E.Col10 <> A.Col10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of those joins is not unique, sql server will update *A.Col10* with every *E.Col10* value that matches your query, so at the end there might be the same amount of rows in the second query as in the first statement
For example - there are 81 A values and 11 E values, one A value match one E value, so sql server will update each A value 10 times = 810. The final result is the same(one A value match one E value), so when you select those values you still get 810 results.

Comment: But if the values have been updated 1 or 10 time to A.Col10 = E.Col10 then AND E.Col10 <> A.Col10 should be false

Comment: Yeah, it is related to 1-M relationship among tables, so SQL Server is updating A->B then says that B should be A. I've now made uniqueness in my table and my problem is resolved. Thanks for your answer.